# How to determine if a reaction proceeds via SN1, SN2, E1 or E2 mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

> [image]
>   Give the main product and reaction type: S<sub>N</sub>1, S<sub>N</sub>2, E1 ,  E2.

As the 1-bromohexane is primary and the nucleophile a strong unhindered base, the reaction should be a S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction. However, the solvent $\ce{EtOH}$ is a polar protic solvent which favours S<sub>N</sub>1/E1 reactions. In addition, the temperature of the reaction is quite high and high temperatures favour the formation of elimination reactions, thus the reaction should be E1.
But an E1 doesn't require a strong base, or else an E2 reaction would take place at the beginning. So does that make this reaction an E2 reaction? Am I thinking correctly on how to consider all the different parts of the reaction?

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{EtO-}$ is a strong base, as well as a strong nucleophile, and the temperature is not too high. Therefore a mixture of products is most likely to be formed, where substitution will lead to the major and elimination will lead to the minor product.
Also, the reactant is a primary halide. So, in substitution, S<sub>N</sub>2 will be favoured, whereas in elimination E2 will be favoured.
So, final product will be,

- Ethoxy hexane (via S<sub>N</sub>2) (major)
- Hex-1-ene (via E2) (minor). (Maybe, a very little amount of hex-2-ene may also form by very very small fraction of E1).

Comment: Why is Sn2 major? I'm having difficult time understanding how a polar protic solvent can result in a Sn2 reaction. Isn't elimination reactions favoured in polar protic solvents?

Comment: @J.Se [take a look at this](http://www.aceorganicchem.com/blog/e1-e2-sn1-sn2/), will try to post a bit more detailed explanation.

Comment: As a general rule, carbocations do not form in the presence of strong bases.  This means that $\ce{S_N1}$ or $\ce{E1}$ mechanisms are ruled out immediately.

It is important to look at all of the factors that are at play in the reaction: the alkyl halide, the nucleophile/base, the solvent and the temperature.  It is the cumulative effect of these that determines the major product, not any one of them alone.